# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply' Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object when running karma/jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, require, karma-runner

I'm trying to get tests to run using a combination of requireJS, AngularJS, Karma and Jasmine.

I have a super simple spec which does some very basic tests, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
```

My configuration files can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/owzzz/6582481

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
beforeEach(angular.module(settings.appName));   //angular.module() is to recreate a module
```

to

```
beforeEach(module(settings.appName)); //use module() to get the module and then inject to the test
```

Comment: When I do this, I get `ReferenceError: module is not defined`.  Can you advise?

Comment: I am here as well so one way gets the OP error and then I do this change gets the error you just said. I need to understand how to get my main app.js and the maincontroller.js going as a concept here. Are we actually getting the angular framework to run ? It feels like we are just kind of faking it - fine but its not working because of these errors. And nothing I find online is quite helping me get it.

Comment: @zsong here settings means whether it is object or config items of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference angular-mocks.js to get module to work.